# Invalid range error in Jtable when i use TableRowSorter

Tags: java, swing, tablesorter

When I use TableRowSorter on my table I get an invalid range error, but when I delete jTableWells.setRowSorter(rowSorter), all it works successfully.

```
this.rowSorter = new TableRowSorter(jTableWells.getModel());
jTableWells.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

searchTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      String text = searchTextField.getText();
      if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
      rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
      } else {
          rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
      }
   }
   @Override
   public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      String text = searchTextField.getText();
      if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
         rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
      } else {
         rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
      }
   }
});
```

When I try to update the table with displayTableWells() after adding a new row, I got the error of Invalid range:

```
private int addNewRecord() {
    try{     
            ...
            st.executeUpdate(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
            if ( rs.next() ) {   
                ...                     
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved ");
            }                
            displayTableWells();// for update the table                
        }    
    } 
    ...
}

private void displayTableWells() {        
    int i;
    int count;
    String a[];
    String header[] = {"col1","col2","col3"};   
    count = header.length;
    DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel();
    //First set the Table header
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        tm.addColumn(header[i]);
    }

    a = new String[count];
    try 
    {
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT col1,col2,col3 from table ORDER 
        BY createdon DESC");           
         while (rs.next())
        {
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            tm.addRow(a); //Adding the row in table model
            jTableWells.setModel(tm);
        }    
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
     ...
    }
}
```

The error as bellow :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
>       at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted(DefaultRowSorter.java:864)
>     at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4270)    at
>   javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4118)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)     at
>   javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(AbstractTableModel.java:231)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:376)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(DefaultTableModel.java:350)
>     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(DefaultTableModel.java:361)
>     at
>   org.geotools.geophysicsdbmaven.NewWell.displayTableWells(NewWell.java:474)

Comment: whats happens when you remove whole public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

Comment: When I remove removeUpdate, I get that error: is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) in DocumentListner

Comment: The problem is not in removeUpdate, but in setRowSorter. because when I remove setRowSorter, all works fine.

Comment: then this question isn't answerable, based on description, nor on the code posted, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variable for JTable/XxxTableModel