# invalid range exception with setAutoCreateRowSorter()

Tags: java, jtable, tablesorter

I am getting an Invalid Range Exception for my JTable when I use setAutoCreateRowSorter().  If I remove the setAutoCreateRowSorter, the problem goes away, but I am no longer able to sort the table.  Also, if I try setting up the sorter directly:

```
myTable.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model));
```

I still get the same error.

This is as close to a SSCCE as I think I can get to convey the issue.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTestTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private MyTestAbstractTableModel model = new MyTestAbstractTableModel();
    private int selectedRow = -1;


    public void setList(ArrayList arrayList) {
        model.setList(arrayList);
    }

    public MyTestTable() {
        initComponents();

        myTable.setModel(model);
        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);  // Error here
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        myTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Select", "First name", "Last name"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(myTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new 
javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(

layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(187, 187, 187)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(243, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(

layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<MyTest> myTestList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyTest myEntry = new MyTest(false, "Joe");
        myTestList.add(myEntry);
        MyTestTable myTestTable = new MyTestTable();
        myTestTable.setList(myTestList);
        myTestTable.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable myTable;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public class MyTestAbstractTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"Select", "First Name"};

        private ArrayList<MyTest> myTestList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void setList(ArrayList<MyTest> myList) {
            this.myTestList = myList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return myTestList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Object value = null;
            MyTest myTest = myTestList.get(row);

            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    value = myTest.getSelected();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = myTest.getFirstName();
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override    
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
            MyTest myTest = myTestList.get(row);
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    if (value instanceof Boolean)
                        myTest.setSelected((boolean)value);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myTest.setFirstName((String)value);
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);  // Exception points to here
        }
    }

    public static class MyTest {

        private Boolean selected;
        private String firstName;

        public MyTest() {
        }

        public MyTest(Boolean selected, String firstName) {
            this.selected = selected;
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public boolean getSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem occurs when I click the checkbox on the table.  This is as close to a SSCCE as I think I can get to convey the issue.  If I take away the sorter, the problem does not persist.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:896)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:915)
    at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4264)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4118)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
    at MyTestTable$MyTestAbstractTableModel.setValueAt(MyTestTable.java:151)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.actionPerformed(DefaultCellEditor.java:385)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.repostEvent(BasicTableUI.java:948)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicTableUI.java:1164)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This part specifically sticks out to me:

```
at MyTestTable$MyTestAbstractTableModel.setValueAt(MyTestTable.java:151)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330327/invalid-range-error-in-jtable-when-i-use-tablerowsorter) is the closest thing I can find similar to my problem, but it is not answered.  How do I implement the table sorter without receiving this error?

Comment: Note: ["When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates;"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I resolved my issue by changing the row and column values passed in fireTableCellUpdated(row, column); to fireTableCellUpdated(row - 1, column - 1);

Comment: Nevermind, it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.